# Why do I seem to type faster on my Ubuntu Virtual Machine (in Terminal)?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, io

I notice that when I type in terminal on my Ubuntu VM launched via VirtualBox, the keyboard input is very slick, smooth, and fast.

Is it because the latency of keypress to screen has a faster setting somewhere on the Ubuntu VM?
Deleting seems faster too (although this may be more easily explained than why typing letters seems faster -- perhaps there is some "acceleration" in the deletion?)

Why is this so? I kinda like how fast it is, and would add the setting to my Mac if I could.

Comment: I imagine that is something in the way ubuntu kernel reacts to keyboard, doubt it is something that can added to Mac.  Usually a VM would have a bit of a lag compared to an installed system.  This site not really good for Mac questions.  Maybe try a Mac site for speeding up keyboard, should be one or more with stack exchange and you can connect your login here with another.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning deleting (and changing the cursor position with arrows), the slickness may come from different delay and rate settings of the autorepeat (that is also called typematic).

In ubuntu you can adjust these with the xset command.

For the Mac, the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x) will make things slicker. Don't forget to log out your session and log in again for the changes to take effect (in the terminal and all other text fields).